# Images Not displayed on Mobile device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

Images display on Browser But not showing on device.

Why?

I tried this

```
 <img src="assets/images/deals/thumbs/bust.png" alt="Product 1">
 <img src="../assets/images/deals/thumbs/bust.png" alt="Product 1">
```

But It's not working.

KIndly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: this might be a work around but try and place the images to the base path instead of a folder it might work then like `src = "bust.png"`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I tried to Many way.But Everything is worked only browser.Not working on Mobile device.: (

Comment: where is your `index.html` located? Also, are you using android or ios to test?

Comment: If you're using android, go to your `.apk` file, change the extension to `.zip`, go into the zip file and check if your assets folder is compiled succesfully

Comment: @Ivaro18 Ya.Compiled successfull assets folder.Bt why dont show image in device.

Answer (score 1):

I have also this issue and solve by move the assets folder under src folder and
use.

`<img src="assets/images/deals/thumbs/bust.png" alt="Product 1">`

not

```
<img src="../assets/images/deals/thumbs/bust.png" alt="Product 1">
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I also tried to this.But Not wrk.

Comment: can you share the path for your image and the path to your html that contain the img tag?

Comment: src/assets/images/IMage Name.jpg.Src is Collection of ts and html files.